# Changing MacOS guest user settings via terminal

Tags: command-line, guest-account

I'm currently attempting to set up some shared Mac devices with a guest user through an MDM (Kandji). Ideally, this needs to be done remotely, which can be done through the MacOS terminal.

By default, when a guest user is enabled through the terminal, the setting to "Limit Adult Websites" turns on. However, this setting causes some problems with our Guest Wi-Fi captive portal, and needs to be turned off. I have been unable to find a way to change this setting via the terminal.

The devices are currently running MacOS 14.4.1.

I have attempted running `sudo cp /Library/Preferences before`, changing the setting manually, running `sudo cp /Library/Preferences after` and checking for any differences with `diff -ur` before after but have been unable to find any .plist that is modified.

I have also looked at documentation for `sysadminctl` and parental controls but was unable to find a way to change this setting for the guest user account.

Thank you for the assistance!